# focus event not dying after removal of class on select tag

Tags: jquery, events, select, focus

I have a select tag with class name like below:

```
<select name="names" id="select" class="change-me">
  <option value="">Select Name</option>
  <option value="saikiran"> Saikiran</option>
  <option value="srikanth">Srikanth</option>
  <option value="ashok">Ashok</option>
</select>
```

This select tag with class name has  function like below:

```
$('select.change-me').on('focus',function(){
  swal("click on fake ajax btn should not bring this popup");
});
```

I have a some action on the page for example a button click on which i am removing class of this select tag.

```
$('#click').on('click',function(){
  $('#select').removeClass('change-me');
});
```

After removal of class name the focus event on select tag is still alive. can anyone tell me why is it happening.

i tried to put up all this in a codepen. please check it below

[Check the pen here](https://codepen.io/saikiranmarripati/pen/OOyVQW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `change` event is bound to the select element. You're removing the class, but you're no longer checking for the class so it makes no difference. You can add a check for the class within your change event to get around this, e.g.

```
$('select.change-me').on('focus',function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('change-me')) {
  swal("click on fake ajax btn should not bring this popup");
  }
});
```

[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oojjxL).

Answer (score 0):

You have binded the function to the `select.change-me` element which is not removed from that element even if the class is removed. you need to `unbind` it as given below.

```
$('#click').on('click',function(){
  $("select.change-me").unbind("focus");
  $('#select').removeClass('change-me');
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPKKdX

Note that there may be other select element with the same class having the function binded in your HTML and this code will remove them all. So i will suggest to use `id` while using the `unbind` function.